# YUI DataSource.GET possible to use HTTP POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui

Ok we are talking Yahoo YUI3 here:

when sending a request via `DataSource.Get` is it possible to send via POST and not GET. Im sure it is! it has to be but i cant find it in the api docs... there a little confusing.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't send a request via POST with DataSource.GET , I think what you want is [DataSource.IO](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datasource/datasource-io.html)

> Accessing data from a server is easy with DataSource.IO, which uses
>   the IO Utility to retrieve data over HTTP. A DataSchema plugin is used
>   to normalize incoming data into a known format for consistency of
>   usage by other components.

See [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datasource/#io) for an example of how to use it .

Comment: Yep, io is the way to go, supports WebDAV methods and everything. It seems you two are my fellow YUI peeps over the last couple of days eh!

Comment: yes ! , exactly what i was thinking too :)